# Fanout data from Kafka to S3 using kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My kafka gets a wrapper payload in Json format. The wrapper payload looks like this:

```
{
"format": "wrapper",
"time": 1626814608000,
"events": [
  {
    "id": "item1",
    "type": "product1",
    "count": 200
  },
  {
    "id": "item2",
    "type": "product2",
    "count": 300
  }
],
"metadata": {
  "schema": "schema-1"
}
```

}

I should export this to S3. But the catch here is, I should not store the wrapper. Instead, I should be storing the individual events based on the item.
For example, it should be stored in S3 as follows:

`bucket/product1`:

```
{"id": "item1", "type": "product1", "count": 200}
```

`bucket/product2`:

```
{"id": "item2", "type": "product2", "count": 300}
```

If you notice, the input is the wrapper with those events internally. However, my output should be each of those individual events stored in S3 in the same bucket with the `product type` as prefix.

My question is, is it possible to use Kafka Connect to do this? I see they have this [Single Message transformer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html) which seems to be a way to mutate data inside the object, but not to fanout like what I want. Even the signature looks like an `R=>R`
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.java

So based on my research, it does not seem possible. But I want to check if I am missing something before using a different option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforms accept one event and output one event.

You need to use a stream processor such as Kafka Streams branch or flatMap functions to split an array of events into multiple events or multiple topics.